# Disable a css attribute on hover -> right instead of left

Tags: css

I have a div with absolute position. 
It is located **10px from the left**. I would like to transition it to a new location **10px from the right** on hover. Is it possible? I would like to "cancel" the 'left' attribute on hover and include a new 'right' attribute instead:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.9s;
  background-color: blue;
}
div:hover {
  right: 10px;  // Instead of left
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions don't work as you might expect when the transition is from/to an `auto` value. In your example, you're animating the right property from `auto` to `10px`;

You need instead to keep the same property (`left`) to see the transition

```
div:hover {
  left: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

in this case you need to move the element `100%` left minus its width (`30px`) minus the margin (`10px`). If you don't know in advance the width of the element you could just add a negative `translateX`

```
div:hover {
  left: calc(100% - 10px);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

---

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gepVWV)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible..

```
div:hover {
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;  // Instead of left
}
```

BUT - as a 'hover' attribute, the DIV will fly over to the right, and then you won't be hovered over it anymore.. So it will react strangely.